# HttpServletRequest in schedulers - Java Spring

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, servlets, scheduled-tasks

I have to get my servlet path dynamically for some actions. Following is my code to get object:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ( (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() ).getRequest();
request.getSession().getServletContext();
```

This is working fine in application, but when i run this through Scheduler, it fails to get the correct  `request.getSession().getServletContext();`

Please suggest solution following is my schedule class.

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

public class CronServices
{

/**
 * Send Reminders.
 * Daily at  AM
 */
@Scheduled( cron = "* */10 * * * ?" )
public void initReminders()
{
    EmailComponent emailComponent;
    emailComponent = new EmailComponent();
    emailComponent.sendReminders();
}



}
```

Comment: If you're inside a scheduled job, you're not responding to any HTTP request, so there is no request available. Get the data needed by the scheduled job from the request when creating and scheduling the job, not from inside the scheduled job itself.

Comment: It 'fits'? Do you mean it *fails?* If so, fails how? Be specific.

Comment: @PankajSinghai Please comment your edits correctly. Not one of those was a grammatical mistake.

Comment: @JBNizet can you please assist me, where exactly i could get servelet Context

Comment: Not until you post the code that starts this scheduled task.

Comment: @EJP - I have just added the code.